# For each on target of Makefile variable

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I've makefile which looks like follows

`apps = app1 app2 app3`

`all: dir app1 app2 app3 zip cleanup`

Now I want to do some loop on the list of `apps` varible,

something like

```
`loop on apps

endloop`
```

Is it possible in makefile to loop on it, I need to do loop on `apps` varible list

**update**

lets say this variable(`apps`) is **generated** by my program in the `make` file, which provide for each project diffrent values of apps, sometimes its `apps= app1 app2` sometimes its `apps= app1` and sometimes can be 20 apps or more `apps= app1 app2 appN`

How can I iterate on `apps` varible and do something, for example in each iteration print something like:

```
now im in `app1`
now im in `app2`
etc
```

When trying the following

```
.PHONY: foo
all: foo
APPS = app1 app2 app3 app4
foo : $(APPS)
    for $$f in $(APPS); do echo $$f is here; done
```

I got following error:

`make: *** No rule to make target`app1', needed by `foo'.  Stop.`

Comment: What is the *exact* thing you want to on that list. You could use a shell command with a `for` loop...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - can you please provide example? How can I iterate and print the value from apps in each iteration ?

Comment: I might provide one if you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52282549/edit) your question to improve it and tell exactly what you want to do on that list. But I am not sure to understand what you want to do...

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by "print the value from apps" .. Your question is really unclear.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - lets say this variable(apps) is generated by my golang program in the make file, which provide for each project diffrent values of apps, sometimes its `apps= app1 app2` sometimes its `apps= app1 ` and sometimes can be 20 apps or more `apps= app1 app2 appN`

Comment: Never comment your question, but please **edit your question** since it needs *a lot* of improvement. Don't be shy in adding three paragraphs and explaining your motivation. If you can, provide some [MCVE]

Comment: Even with the edit, I don't understand what you want to do. A lot of existing `Makefile`-s have shell `for` loops. For example, the source of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) has `Makefile.in` which generates `Makefile` and both have `for` loops

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - can you please take a look now on the last edit ?

Comment: Even with the edit, the question stays unclear. I voted to close it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see you've gone back and forth a bit, so let me just make a comment which may or may not help.

In general you don't write loops inside make recipes, because make itself provides "looping".  So when you write a rule like:

```
all: app1 app2 app3 app4
```

make will try to build each one of those prerequisites, one at a time.  So if you wanted to have a makefile that echoed a line for each entry in the `apps` variable you would do it like this:

```
all: $(apps)

$(apps):
        @echo $@
```

This tells make to start with a target `all` and try to "build" each of its prerequisites which are the values in the `apps` variable.

Then you define a rule for how to build the apps, and for each one you say that the rule is `echo $@` where `$@` is an [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) that expands to the currently-building target.

In make, the syntax:

```
foo bar biz:
        some command
```

is shorthand for, and identical to, writing:

```
foo:
        some command
bar:
        some command
biz:
        some command
```

The crucial thing when writing makefiles is that you think how to write a rule to create *one* file (target) from zero or more prerequisite files.  Then you let make worry about how to connect all those prerequisites together and order them properly.

*ETA*
If you want a special rule for one particular target in a long list held in the `$(apps)` variable, you can do this:

```
$(filter-out bar,$(apps)):
        @echo print $@

bar:
        some other command
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I need :) 1+ , one question, in case I want that for the  `bar` run `some other command`    , how can I do that ?

Comment: You can either write out all the rules as in my last example rather than writing one rule for all `$(apps)`.  If you have lots of apps but want only one of them to be different, you'll have to do something like change `$(apps):` target to `$(filter-out bar,$(apps)):` instead so it doesn't create a rule for `bar`, then create a separate rule for `bar:` that does what you want.

Comment: can you please add it to the answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want something like (and I assume that some *other* part of the `Makefile` describes how `app1` and `app2` etc... should be built with appropriate rules).

```
foo: app1 app2 app3 app4 
     for f in $^ ; do echo $$f is here ; done
```

or (slightly better)

```
APPS = app1 app2 app3 app4
foo : $(APPS)
     for f in $(APPS); do echo $$f is here; done
```

and you might be interested in the [`foreach` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html) in make (or perhaps its [`eval` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html), perhaps mixed with something else)

At last, your makefile (or some parts [included](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) in it) could be generated by some (shell, AWK, Python, ...) script (or even another program coded in C++, Java, Ocaml, whatever you want)

I recommend using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/), as `remake -x`, to debug your `Makefile`

You could also generate some `submakefile` and run `$(MAKE) -f submakefile` in some recipe.

I strongly recommend taking at least one hour in reading *entirely* the [documentation of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node) before coding something in your `Makefile`. And you could also need to read the [documentation of `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/).

At last, you might consider some other build automation tool, like [`ninja`](http://ninja-build.org/) (whose philosophy is *different* : the `build.ninja` file is expected to be *generated* and *you* have to provide a generator for it)

For your next question, please provide some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I try like your answer and get error, `make: *** No rule to make target `app1', needed by `foo'.  Stop.
` any idea?

Comment: Show an [MCVE] in your question

Comment: Thanks, but I copy your exaple as-is and its not working, same error as before, does it works for you?

Comment: My example is not intended to work in isolation. You need more rules in such a `Makefile`

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I dont have rules for the app1 to appN , can I overcome it somehow ?

Comment: Yes, you generate these rules.

Comment: and without generating those rules, there is no other option ?

Comment: I don't know, because I still don't understand your issue. Smells badly like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: To provide the whole picture will be very difficult , do you want me to do it on the chat ?

Comment: I'm giving up the idea of helping you more without an improved question. If your software is free, you could give a link to its URL

Comment: ok i'll try to improve it tomorrow, to be more specific and hope you could help, give you 1+ for helping me :)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `for $$f in $^ ; do echo $$f is here ; done` is probably not what you had in mind. Wasn't it `for f in $^ ; do echo $$f is here ; done`, instead? Same typo in the other proposal.