# Makefile loop on folders and get the names dynmaically

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I've `projects` which include makefile under the root project

like

```
project
 -Folder1
 -Folder2
 -app1
 -service1
 -Makefile
```

Now I want inside the makefile loop on the folders (under the root. i.e. under `project`) and print the folder
name, the tricky part here that the folders can be changed from `projectX` to `projectN` , is it possible?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [Listing only directories using ls in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352290/listing-only-directories-using-ls-in-bash-an-examination)

Comment: @arjoonn - can I use it for looping on directory and provide each name ?, I need the `loop`

Comment: sure. `ls -d */` should list the directories and you can loop over it using something like `for dir in */; do echo $dir; done`

Comment: @arjoonn: beware that `ls -d */` will exit with non-zero status if there are no directories to list. Maybe not what is expected in a make recipe. Moreover, looping in recipes using the shell's loop constructs is not really the _make way_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ tree -F    
.
|-- Folder1/
|-- Folder2/
|-- Makefile
|-- app1
`-- service1

2 directories, 3 files

$ cat Makefile
DIRS     := $(notdir $(shell find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d))
DIRNAMES := $(addprefix print-folder-name-,$(DIRS))

.PHONY: $(DIRNAMES) print-folder-names

print-folder-names: $(DIRNAMES)

$(DIRNAMES): print-folder-name-%:
    @printf '%s\n' '$*'

$ make print-folder-names
Folder2
Folder1
```

Everything is quite simple and easy to understand. The only subtlety is probably the [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) `$(DIRNAMES): print-folder-name-%:`. It is equivalent to one single rule per folder:

```
print-folder-name-Folder1:
    @printf '%s\n' 'Folder1'

print-folder-name-Folder2:
    @printf '%s\n' 'Folder2'
```

Of course, in the same rule you can do anything you like (else than printing its name) for each folder; just adapt the recipe. The `$*` automatic variable expands as the stem of the pattern (the folder name in this case).

**EDIT**: if you also want to print something special for some folders, you can also use target-specific make variables:

```
$ cat Makefile
...
print-folder-name-Folder2: SOMEMORETEXT := ' foo'

$(DIRNAMES): print-folder-name-%:
    @printf '%s%s\n' '$*' $(SOMEMORETEXT)

$ make print-folder-names
Folder2 foo
Folder1
```

Comment: Thank you 1+ , can it's done by loop. the idea that I need to run on the list of folder in the make file and for each folder I need to execute some command...

Comment: Make loops naturally. In the example I show it loops over each folder and prints its name. The static pattern rule is the same as if you had one separate rule for each folder, with the same recipe. Look maybe at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282549/for-each-on-target-of-makefile-variable/52284299#52284299) for an explanation.

Comment: Not sure that I got it ...:( yours example is working great excepts that I need a loop which prints each folder name...

Comment: something that `@printf '%s\n' '$*'` this will be inside the loop..., is it possible?

Comment: `@printf '%s\n' '$*'` is already inside a loop: the loop that make will create to build all targets listed in the `$(DIRNAMES)` variable.

Comment: yes I understand :) , is there a way to convert it somehow to for each loop?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you want to add another loop and what it could be used for. Is this an assignment in a course about shell programming?

Comment: ohh, no it isn't I just want to use `if else`  inside for example if `foldername==Folder2` print `foo`  else `bar` and I think in the way it's a bit more complicated

Comment: I really don't understand. Do you want to print the name of the folder, `foo`, `bar`, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I want to print the name of the folder, but in case I've folder for example 'folder2` print the name and just for it add `foo` , I just want to understand how it can be done in a bit more complex secnarion when I need the value of the variable ...

Comment: Edited my answer to show you how to do this with make target-specific variables.

Comment: sorry I need to leave for a while, now im checking it.

Comment: btw, when i use the code it even prints hidden folders such as `.idea` or  .`git` etc, can it be avoided simply ?

Comment: @shopiaT: sure, just adapt the `find` options to skip `.*` names (I am sure SO already has answers to this other question).

Comment: Thanks a lot I've closed the question :) , it will be great if you can elborate just on  the first `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`  and the second `addprefix`   what the purpose for them

Comment: I think I understand, not going deeper to other folders inside recursive